# How can I use code to add tables to a Wordpress site using the block editor?

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a Python script that reads a CSV file, performs some calculations, and then publishes the results in the form of a table on my WordPress site. The tables are currently being created using the classic editor, but I would like to change their appearance to block editor as they look nice. Is there a way to modify the table properties inside the code or let code create them in block editors when posting the results using the in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

The Block Editor saves block content into markup, eg. for a simple table block:

**post_content**

```html
<!-- wp:table -->
<figure class="wp-block-table">
<table><thead><tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>Apples</td><td>Banana</td></tr></tbody></table>
</figure>
<!-- /wp:table -->
```

Assuming your Python script outputs a valid HTML table, you could wrap the table output with:

```html
<!-- wp:table --><figure class="wp-block-table"> ... <figure><!-- /wp:table -->
```

This would define your table output as a block when inserted into `post_content`. The caveat is that *the markup must be valid and parsable* to be later edited it within the Block Editor and display correctly.